# Why this code doesn't compile?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Is there any difference in these codes:

```
std::string dirName = argv[1];
MyRecordDatabaseType myDB(Selector<std::string>((std::string)dirName));
```

and

```
std::string dirName = argv[1];
MyRecordDatabaseType myDB(Selector<std::string>(dirName));
```

I have no idea why the second version doesn't compile.

The compiler tells me:

```
error: request for member ‘createGroupWriter’ in ‘myDB’, which is of non-class type ‘main(int, char**)::MyRecordDatabaseType(Selector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >)’
```

at line:

```
MyRecordDatabaseType::writer_type myWriter(myDB.createGroupWriter(groupName));
```

And sorry, but I can't show you the code of Selector or any other class.

Maybe you can help me without that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the difference is that this line

```
MyRecordDatabaseType myDB(Selector<std::string>(dirName));
```

can also be written like

```
MyRecordDatabaseType myDB(Selector<std::string>  dirName);
```

and is a declaration of a function `myDB` that returns `MyRecordDatabaseType`.

See [C++ most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)

Comment: @iammilind: it's not that it can be removed. It's more like you can add them freely.